# android HttpRequest via service every 3 seconds

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, service

I just want fetch data and show it on a toast message or notification message. So I created a service in Main thread.(UI Thread) And I just started a new thread for fetching data and put it on Logs in Service. Code :

```
public class HelloService extends Service 
{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    MyThread th = new MyThread();
    th.start();
    try 
    {
        th.join();
    } 
catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return START_STICKY;  
}



}

class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        String response;
        String dataToSend = "http://berkrevolution.com";
        Log.i("FROM STATS SERVICE DoBackgroundTask", dataToSend);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(dataToSend);

        try 
        {
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(dataToSend, "UTF-8"));

            // Set up the header types needed to properly transfer JSON
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");

            // Execute POST
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (responseEntity != null) 
            {
                response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
                Log.i("sonuc", response);
            } 
            else 
            {
                response = "{\"NO DATA:\"NO DATA\"}";
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            response = "{\"ERROR\":" + e.getMessage().toString() + "}";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response = "{\"ERROR\":" + e.getMessage().toString() + "}";
        }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error after 20 seconds. The error is :

```
11-22 13:30:44.831: A/libc(29854): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000470 (code=0), thread 29854 (le.project1)
```

I need to make a service which should work 24/7 even main program is closed. But Ever I try to work with services, I got this error. How can I solve this problem?

How I start service in UI Thread:

```
 public void startServ(View view) 
    {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Hey", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelloService.class);
        startService(intent);

    }
```

Comment: This is a very bad design. It'll *kill* phone's battery. Better use GCM Push Notification and run your HTTP Request inside an `IntentService` when you receive a notification. This way you can be friendly to battery and still keep data up to date. GCM high priority messages can also bypass Android 6 Doze mode so you don't have to worry about that too.

Comment: IntentService will be closed If I close main program :)

Comment: That's the whole point of GCM. Your Service should not run indefinitely making HTTP Requests. You can start a new wakeful IntentService when you a Push Notification in your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: It should also make an httppost in service even I try with GCM. So my problem is that when I try httppost in a service, my program crashes as given error.

Comment: That happens when Android thinks UI is hung. `Service` run on main UI Thread and thus might be causing that error. `IntentService` run on their own thread and thus won't cause this issue.

Comment: Yeah I know what you are talking about but when I close UI thread, IntentService also will be terminated. So I don't want this situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95844/discussion-between-sourabh-and-alihan-avci).

Comment: if your `MyThread` thread doesn't leave its `run` method and you are calling `th.join();` you will be waiting forever...